# LogStash in a loop

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration

I am running Elasticsearch, Kibana and Logstash version 8.9.1.

My Logstash is in a loop:

```
[2023-09-08T22:05:38,932][DEBUG][org.logstash.instrument.metrics.ExtendedFlowMetric] RetentionWindow{policy=current id=1335924351} forced-compaction result (captures: `3` span: `PT10.0136766S`)
[2023-09-08T22:05:38,932][DEBUG][org.logstash.instrument.metrics.ExtendedFlowMetric] RetentionWindow{policy=current id=346568156} forced-compaction result (captures: `3` span: `PT10.014082599S`)
[2023-09-08T22:05:42,416][DEBUG][org.logstash.execution.PeriodicFlush][main] Pushing flush onto pipeline.
[2023-09-08T22:05:43,468][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.cgroup] One or more required cgroup files or directories not found: /proc/self/cgroup, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu
[2023-09-08T22:05:43,558][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"G1 Young Generation"}
[2023-09-08T22:05:43,558][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"G1 Old Generation"}
```

Below is the config for logstash.  Can anyone give me an idea why this is stuck in this loop?

```
`input {
  file {
    type => "json"
    path => "D:/01-evidence/json/*.json"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "D:/logstash/data/queue/sincedb_json_ingest_.log"
    codec => "json"
  }
}

filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
    target => "cloudtrail"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch{
        hosts => ["http://x.x.x.x:9200"]
        user => user
        password => "pass"
                index => "aws-cloudtrail"
    }
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}`
```

I have tried this config from the command line:

```
logstash -f cloudtrail.conf --log.level=debug
```